# I want to protect multiple routes under specific path in middleware, is there a way for me to do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes, middleware

I want to protect multiple routes under specific path in Next.js middleware. For Example, I want to protect all routes under /admin
and redirect it back to / .

```js
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
}
// I don't want to manually write all the routes
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/", "/admin/accounts", etc...],
};

// Is there a way I could do like this 
export const config = {
  matcher: "/admin/**",
};
```

I want to protect multiple routes under specific path in Next.js middleware. For Example, I want to protect all routes under /admin
and redirect it back to / .

Comment: Your current matcher is not working?